How to recognize Uppercase word in Korn Shell?
I want recognize Upper case word passed in argument of a script.
Here my script test.ksh :
var=$1
if [[ ${var} == +([A-Z]) ]]
then
        echo "$var is UPPERCASE word"
else
        echo "$var is not UPPERCASE word"
fi


./test.ksh AZ return AZ is UPPERCASE word nice !
./test.ksh PO return PO is UPPERCASE word nice !
./test.ksh az return az is not UPPERCASE word nice !
However
./test.ksh po return  po is UPPERCASE word sad :/
What is wrong with this script ?

Do you have #!/usr/bin/ksh or similar as first line of script? What is your operating-system, and version?  Which version of korn shell are you using? That scriptlet will work with current supported ksh versions on linux x64, as long as you code properly.

Thank you very much mao.
I don't work in my own system, and indeed there is no /usr/bin/ksh installed.
I used the command  readlink -f /proc/$$/exe to know what system use to execute my script and the answer is /usr/bin/bash version 4.4.20.
I changed the condition in the if statement like this :

if [[ ${var} =~ ^[A-Z]+$ ]]

and it works fine.

If you didn't know, you can accept your own answer after 48 hrs (I think 48) and gain valuable reputation points. (I wish there was more focus on using =~ with globbing/REs, this is a perfect example of why, The code in the O.P. passed shellcheck /-; )
